# Are there efficient algorithm to split a discrete function into piecewise convex functions?

Tags: functions, convex-analysis, discrete-calculus

Hi guys let's say we have a function $f(x)$ where $x$ belongs to a discrete range of values (but finite).

Are there algorithms to split $f$ as piecewise convex functions? If yes what about the hypothesis on $f$?

If it is not possible for discrete function is it possible for continuous function? (i.e. defined on a continuous set)?

Comment: Well, it depends on the level sets of $f$, etc. This paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.3771v1.pdf studies a slight more general problem: convexity of functions defined piecewise.

Comment: I'm having a look to the paper. I forgot to say that $f$ is univariate, sorry.